# Angularjs - How to merge one bo-class with one ng-class using the lazy loading?

Tags: angularjs, lazy-loading, ng-class, bindonce

I am very confuse by the version 1.3+ of angularjs, before I was using bindonce and now we have the lazy loading with '::'.

I didn't find how I can bind only one class of a multiple ng-class.

This was my pevious code:

```
<a [...] bo-class="{'tuto': user.tutorial}" ng-class="{liked: liked == true}">[...]</a>
```

I need to use : ng-class"**::**{'tuto': user.tutorial}" and to keep my second ng-class.

How I can do to merge one bo-class using lazy loading with one ng-class which is bind ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Try to use this an ugly workaround.

```
<a 
  bo-attr 
  bo-attr-class="user.tutorial?'tuto':''" 
  ng-class="{liked: liked == true}">[...]</a>
```

Comment: I don't want to use bindonce (bo-*) anymore. I want to use the official bindonce of angularjs using ::.

For example : <a [...] ng-class="::{'tuto': user.tutorial}" ng-class="{liked: liked == true}">[...]</a>

But as you see, it won't work because I can't have two time the attribute ng-class.

Answer (score 0):

for bo-class you can use:

bo-class="{'class1' : condition1,'class2' : condition2}"

and so on,
basically you can have key value pairs that it will evaluate every pair.

Comment: Thanks @Mustafa ! However I want to use ng-class="::{'class1' : condition1,'class2' : condition2}" and not bo-*.